# What's the difference between ODAC 12c R4 and ODP.NET, Managed Driver from Nuget?

Tags: oracle, ado.net, nuget, nuget-package

What's the difference between ODAC 12c R4 and ODP.NET, Managed Driver from Nuget? Are they the exactly same thing or do they differ? This has always confused me.

I'm asking because I'm having the following difficulties:

When I try to use the Oracle Managed Data Access from Nuget to connect to a database using Advanced Security Option (ASO), I get the ora-12537 error. Most Google searches point to the fact that ASO is not supported, which is the reason for my error.

Note: I am able to connect to non secure database

The oracle documents confirm this

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/InstallConfig.htm#ODPNT8159

> There is no support for Oracle Advanced Security Option (ASO)
>   encryption. Setting SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER to required is not
>   supported, resulting in client connection establishment failure. Not
>   setting SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER or setting it to any other valid
>   value is supported.

But on the Oracle forum it is mention that support has been added.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3764453

> Yes, ODAC 12c R4, which is out, supports managed ODP.NET encryption
>   with ASO.

Does the Nuget package provide support for ASO?

**Edit:** 
Looks like Oracle Managed Provider as of October 2015 provides support for ASO, but not all features of ASO are supported, for example Oracle Advanced Security Data Integrity is currently not supported. See
[Source](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3868095?sr=inbox&ru=44136)

Comment: ODAC(Oracle Data Access Components) include sevreal non managed dll's and installs some of then in GAC. Main managed dll in ODAC is Oracle.DataAccess.dll with complete oracle functionally working like advanced security and spatial data etc. But nuget odp.net has less futures and main dll is oracle.manageddataaccess.dll with less than 7 MB size.

Comment: So ODP is different from ODAC? Asking because the doc I reference is for the ODP.

Comment: Not completely. Odac include odp that is not full managed. But nuget odp package is full managed. Also ODAC Setup package is Different for x86 and x64. But nuget managed dataaccess is architecture aware.

Comment: Okay, so it would be correct to say that the Nuget package since "full managed" does not support ASO as indicated in the document referenced?

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! So many variables in the world of programming.